# Filter specific groups out in dplyr where each group has multiple key columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to do something like this

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(
  key1 = sample(5, 100, replace = TRUE),
  key2 = sample(5, 100, replace = TRUE),
  val = rnorm(100)
) |> group_by(key1, key2)


keysToDrop <- tibble(
  key1 = c(5, 2),
  key2 = c(3, 2)
)

df |>
  left_join(keysToDrop |> mutate(dropMe = TRUE), by = c("key1", "key2")) |>
  filter(is.na(dropMe))
```

In my case I have multiple dataframes I want to filter separately and I also have the group keys I want to drop defined as a separate dataframe.

The above code works well enough but I am wondering if there is a more direct way, with some feature in dplyr designed specifically for this operation.

Comment: `df |> anti_join(keysToDrop)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like an `anti_join()`, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(
  key1 = sample(5, 100, replace = TRUE),
  key2 = sample(5, 100, replace = TRUE),
  val = rnorm(100)
) |> group_by(key1, key2)


keysToDrop <- tibble(
  key1 = c(5, 2),
  key2 = c(3, 2)
)

output1 <- df |>
  left_join(keysToDrop |> mutate(dropMe = TRUE), by = c("key1", "key2")) |>
  filter(is.na(dropMe)) %>%
  select(-dropMe)

output2 <- df |>
  anti_join(keysToDrop)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(key1, key2)`

all.equal(output1, output2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: nice! didn't know about `anit_join`. Also, didn't know about reprex!